# Does Self-Invoke JavaScript function will causes stack overflow exception

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout, stack-overflow

Here I have a function that calls itself within a `setTimeout` callback function:

```
function myFunc(){

    // ... I'm doing my jobs here...

    setTimeout(function(){
        myFunc() //self invoke
    },1)
}

myFunc(); // start point
```

Does this code eventually will occurs stack overflow exception?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Functions queued via `setTimeout` are only run once the main thread (or whatever thread is currently in progress) is complete - there are no nested calls / nested environments that could cause the overflow you're worried about. If you run this snippet, you'll never run into an error, for example:

```js
function myFunc(i) {
  if (i % 1000 === 0) console.log(i);
  setTimeout(function() {
    myFunc(++i)
  })
}
myFunc(0);
```

The same sort of thing is true for functions that invoke promises that call themselves recursively via `.then` - it's perfectly safe.